# Salesforce Lightning - how to set nooverride for Lightning, but retain override in Classic

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

We are planning to migrate our users from Classic to Lightning with a phased roll out. That means we need to retain all the behaviours of Classic and Lightning in parallel for a period of time.

That's working well, except for Button Overrides. There doesn't appear to be a way of configuring Lightning to use the standard edit behaviour, while Classic retains an edit form override. For classic the options available are No Override, Custom S-Control and Visual Force Page. However, the only options available for Lightning are Lightning Component or Use the Salesforce Classic override. There's no option for No Override.

We tried writing a custom Aura component to re-direct to the edit page with ?nooverride=1 but that doesn't work - the user is re-directed, but once the edit page is closed and saved, the user is left on a blank page, not re-directed back to the view of the edited page.

Does anyone have a workaround, or explanation as to why this seems not to be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you specify a Url as a retURL parameter Salesforce will redirect to that url.

Now in Salesforce Classic view page means `xxx.salesforce.com/IdOfRecordToView` so You can try retURL parameter in URL with the value of Salesforce Record id which you are editing

example : `xxx.salesforce.com/a010000000000qn/e?retURL=%2Fa010000000000qn&nooverride=1`

Comment: Hi, tried that. That doesn't have any effect. The retUrl is ignored.